# Preview multiple images but delete the old ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, upload

i have this preview images script:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $(function() {
            // Multiple images preview in browser
            var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

                if (input.files) {
                    var filesAmount = input.files.length;

                    for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();

                        reader.onload = function(event) {
                            $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                        }

                        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                    }
                }

            };

            $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
                imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
            });
        });

    });
</script>

<input type="file" multiple id="gallery-photo-add">
<div class="gallery"></div>
```

when I select some images, say 10 different images, I can see them, but when I want to select another 10 new images they overlap the first ones, what I want is to delete the first ones and only the new ones appear.